# setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

Here is some HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque magnam expedita aspernatur suscipit ea ad nisi corporis sequi labore consequatur odit, impedit quia quisquam inventore, recusandae similique esse excepturi distinctio.</li>
  <li>Susan</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vitae consequatur vel nostrum? Sunt, quas iure libero aut laborum facere unde quidem dolorem dicta, eaque, eveniet dolore harum iste deleniti.</li>
</ul>
```

and JavaScript:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var firstItem = text.firstChild;
var lastItem = text.lastChild;
firstItem.setAttribute('class', 'complete');
```

And the browser shows this error:

> firstItem.setAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `firstItem.setAttribute('class', 'complete');` because the `firstItem` already have one element in it. You also need to change the `firstChild` and `lastChild` into `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` so that you can use `setAttribute()` method on them:

```js
var text = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

var firstItem = text.firstElementChild;

var lastItem = text.lastElementChild;
firstItem.setAttribute('class', 'complete');
lastItem.setAttribute('class', 'done');
```

```css
.complete{
  color: red;
}
.done {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque magnam expedita aspernatur suscipit ea ad nisi corporis sequi labore consequatur odit, impedit quia quisquam inventore, recusandae similique esse excepturi distinctio.</li>
    <li>Susan</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad vitae consequatur vel nostrum? Sunt, quas iure libero aut laborum facere unde quidem dolorem dicta, eaque, eveniet dolore harum iste deleniti.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RuslanAlmukhanov please check the updated answer. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you Ankita, you use another function firstElementChild, that is the function firstChild is not relevant ?

Comment: @RuslanAlmukhanov `firstChild` is quite primitive than `firstElementChild` so it is better to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add a small point that other answers fail to mention.

In the following HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>
```

... the `firstChild` of `<ul>` is actually a text node (containing whitespace) rather than an `<li>` node. This would not be the case if the HTML had been:

```html
<ul><li>some text</li></ul>
```

At any rate, that is the reason why `firstElementChild` or `document.querySelector("ul > li")` solve this problem; the text node is not considered.